# JuliaBox - Console Copy Paste - Clipboard - Not working

Tags: console, clipboard, copy-paste, julia, jupyter

Machine: Windows7, browser: Firefox (lastest/recent).

I'm using Julia browser console (JuliaBox) to learn Julia. It works!

I not able to do the following though. 
[image]
If I select some text in the console and right click > Copy it, the data is not getting copied to the global/system clipboard buffer.

I can open a new file within the console (vi new.txt) and there if I paste the data, it works!!

But if I want to copy the same selected/copied data outside of JuliaBox console, it doesn't work (i.e. if I try to paste it to Notepad++ or in outlook email, word doc etc).

Am I missing anything?

ALSO -- If I copy anything from notepadd++ / word doc or any data from an opened app or browser window, then I **CAN'T** paste it to JuliaBox console!! even if I try Control+C / Right Click Copy to copy the data.

Comment: which OS are you using? on Mac, `Cmd+C`, `Cmd+v` works for me.

Comment: I'm Windows. Browser is Firefox for Juliabox. Using Cntl+C, Control+V -- worked when I copied it from JuliaBox console and pasted it on another application (like notepadd++ etc). But, this way, I don't see why I can't paste now in JuliaBox itself !!!! i.e. after copying, if I open "vi 1.txt" and try to paste the lines (insert more > mouse right/middle click), it didn't paste anything what I copied using "Control+C" and wanted the same using Control+V or right click and selecting PASTE option. The copied data in buffer while using Control+C --OR-- Right click + Copy  is not same.

Comment: Vice versa situation == If I copy something from another tool/application (for ex: Putty window, notepad++, word) etc, then I can't paste the copied data in JuliaBox console! ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### copy-paste data from JuliaBox console:

use `Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v` on Windows/Linux or `Cmd+c/Cmd+v` on Mac.

#### copy-paste data into JuliaBox console:

a workaround is to use the term.js widget `Paste from browser` in the right-click menu.

this seems to be a bug, the [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/104) says it will be fixed in the future.